# VBA Change form control background color

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to change the background color of a form control checkbox via VBA code. I've tried every variation of code I can find on the internet and am still getting failures.

The line I have currently is below, and is the only one I've found so far that doesn't give me compiler errors. When I run it though I get a "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method" error on executing this line. This is true whether I set it = to xlBlack, RGB(255,255,255) or "11398133" (not black I know, but I was just trying to see if any color would work).

Anyone know what's going on and how I can actually do this?

```
    Sheets("Controls").Shapes.Range(Array("Check Box 8")).BackColor = "11398133"
```

**Answer**
I found the answer. For some reason none of the responses worked, but Johnny's answer did help me get closer to it by loading the right object in memory and I could then use the Locals window to track down the property I wanted.

In the end it was identifying the object as Johnny suggested and then just cb.Interior.Color = xlBlack I was looking for. No .Fill and no .DrawingObject. Not sure what makes this different than others that would make that work that way, but there you go.

So, for any others who come looking, the code that ended up working for me was the simple addition of the below, and you can find out what the Excel name of the object is (Check Box 8 in my case) by selecting it while recording macros.

```
    For Each cb In Sheets("Controls").CheckBoxes
        If cb.Name = "Check Box 8" Then
            cb.Interior.Color = xlNone
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Did you try `.Fill.BackColor`? Also, remove the quotes surrounding the color value.

Comment: Yes, I did indeed try Fill.BackColor, it failed as well. Double quotes didn't make a difference, and I also tried xlBlack and RBG(255,255,255), all to no avail.

Comment: Hey @J.Natael I tried your answer for my excel file and my checkboxes aren't changing color. I might be misunderstanding which background color you're changing, but I am trying to change the background that you manipulate when adjusting the size of the checkbox. I believe its the fill area that text will go in if you have text. Is this the same background you are talking about here?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it for you.  Follow these steps:

1. Make some form check boxes on a sheet
2. Copy the below code into a module (alt F11, insert, module)
3. run SetMacro
4. Save and test

code:

```
Sub SetMacro()
    Dim cb, ws
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each cb In ws.CheckBoxes
            If cb.OnAction = "" Then cb.OnAction = "CheckedUnchecked"
        Next cb
    Next ws
End Sub

Sub CheckedUnchecked()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).DrawingObject
        If .Value = 1 Then
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Else
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        End If
    End With
```

If you're only looking to do it on the active sheet, use this block instead:

```
Sub SetMacro()
    Dim cb
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If cb.OnAction = "" Then cb.OnAction = "CheckedUnchecked"
    Next cb
End Sub

Sub CheckedUnchecked()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).DrawingObject
        If .Value = 1 Then
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Else
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Think its just the `Shapes(id).DrawingObject.Interior.ColorIndex` bit thats needed (to answer the question anyway). Annoying that the worksheet and the userform control have different properties.

Comment: Johnny, I'm doing this in code that is not called by the checkbox itself but by something else, so the Application.Caller isn't of use to me.                            

As best I can tell to replicate your process I'd need to identify the box differently, namely giving its ID to the Shapes feature. How do I find that ID? The above line I used was what was generated by macro recording and clicking on the box so I assumed it would identify it sufficiently.

Comment: Whatever is calling it, have that call SetMacro.  Then you can probably put something like, "If cb.Name = 'YourCheckboxName' then" underneath the "For each cb in Activesheet.Checkboxes" line.  This way, it only performs it for your specified checkbox.

Comment: Thanks. That didn't work but it and your original answer helped me find what did, now noted in the question, appreciate the help!

Comment: Kudos for being able to take what you needed and get the answer that works for you.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you want to set the ForeColor not the BackColor.

Very simply:

> Sub changegColor()
>
> ```
>    Dim wb As Workbook
>    Dim ws As Worksheet
>    Dim cb As Object
>    Dim rng As Range
>
>    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
>    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
>    Set cb = ws.Shapes.Range(1)
>
>    With cb.Fill
>        .Solid
>        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
>    End With
> ```
>
> End Sub